# Architecture suggestions

Tags: c#, architecture

I'm writing a small application that will reset the entire “environment” consisting of various machines and applications.

Machine names are added via config file -  this is read, the appropriate services are stopped and log files deleted.  My problem isn’t how to do this (its already working) a bit more elegantly, but due to my lack of experience, I'm curious of the proper architecture.

Right now I feel it’s a mess, large blocks of code, in 5 different classes (delete, processes management, etc) and I would like to make this available for others to enhance.

For example, Ive been thinking about breaking up the DeleteLog class into separate classes by machine, adding and interface and programming each of them to the interface (Strategy Pattern?).

I've also contemplated using  delegates (to which I'm very clueless, but it's always a good time to learn).

Comment: Although these are custom internal applications, I do not have access to any code.  In order to start and stop applications Im getting the Service name via SystemProcess.ServiceController.GetServices then stopping (or starting) by using ProcessStartInfo and calling sc.exe.

Comment: It seems you are over-enginnering. What you said (stopping processes and services, deleting logfiles) are more appropriately done through scripting, my suggestion is to use powershell. You can learn it easily enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Break it down**

Super High level:

```
Obj-->-->--->

C -> P -> A |
     ^-------
```

- Configuration File/Data is read in (C)
- Data is processed & actions taken (P)
- Results of actions are analysed  (A)
- Feedback to Process section if needed (P <-> A )

Obj represents an "Environment" object (e.g a computer & its related properties), as seen in the diagram it flows forwards through each module.

**Sections:**

Parse Module

Process Module

Feedback (Monitor Module)

based upon the above re-write your classes around those major functions. Each modules methods should reflect its main purpose.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing sounds pretty simple, and it works. 5 classes sounds enough, the danger if you start splitting into fancy patterns is that it becomes harder to read. I'd suggest finishing up and moving on to something else.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of applications are you working with? It is hard to recommend something without actually looking at the specifics of what you are doing... But, perhaps, you can simplify your application by ensuring the applications you are serving have uniform interface for doing things you need. For example, each app has a script in folder X which can do *start*, *restart* and *stop*. You can also add some meta data into these scripts to help you manage the applications. Something like init.d on unix basically. Then your app just reads files from directory X and just runs them.